# VB.Net Button not updating text with new information

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently creating an inventory management system. I've input multiple pc specs which are saved into a text file. From there they are supposed to display on the screen, where I can traverse forward or backwards with buttons which will update the text displayed based on which computer is being viewed.

My issue is within the forward button, When I first add an item I'm able to click forward and the text will update, however if I add any additional items to the list the button does nothing. Through the debugger tool, I found out this is due to every time the button is clicked it's opening the stream reader and then closing, resulting in no new information being displayed. What is a possible workaround for this?

I'm also posting the text file contents below, where I only see the Dell pc specs and cannot traverse to see the "test" specs

Here's a screenshot to help give a better idea. https://prnt.sc/mb2bsd

frmInventory.vb

```
Private Sub btnForward_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnForward.Click
    Dim sr = System.IO.File.OpenText("inventory.txt")

    Dim strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
    txtManufacturer.Text = strInventory
    strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
    txtProcessor.Text = strInventory
    strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
    txtVideo.Text = strInventory
    strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
    txtForm.Text = strInventory
    strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
    txtRam.Text = strInventory
    strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
    txtVram.Text = strInventory
    strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
    txtHd.Text = strInventory
    strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
    chkWireless.CheckState = strInventory

    sr.Close()

End Sub
```

inventory.txt

```
Dell
i5
Nvidia
Desktop
8
2
600
1

Test
Test
Test
Test
Test
Test
Test
0
```

Comment: Already asked. You're always reading the same 8 lines. Nothing will change in the UI (provided that the data has been saved correctly). This is not the way to manage the storage requirements of your application. If you want to keep using a text file, use XML/JSON.

Comment: Yeah I know it's reading the same lines, how do I go about skipping 8 lines to the next pc available? I tried using `strInventory = sr.ReadLine()` 8 times which is not efficient however that did not work either.

Comment: You'ld have to load all the text lines in a `List(Of string)`, then use the List to move forward/backward by the number of lines that compose a *record*. Headache-prone but doable. When adding a new *product*, you'ld have to add the elements the List, then flush the whole content of the List when saving to disc. After a couple of days, you'll have the feeling that you need a specialized, serializable, class to hold the elements values, to be more flexible. Then you'll realize that you'll never be flexible enough...

Comment: Have a look at your previous question - I've added an answer there that should cover this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Move the StreamReader out to Class/Form level like below (with absolutely no error checking!):

```
Private sr As System.IO.StreamReader = Nothing

Private Sub btnForward_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnForward.Click
    If IsNothing(sr) Then
        sr = System.IO.File.OpenText("inventory.txt")
    End If

    If Not sr.EndOfStream Then
        Dim strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
        txtManufacturer.Text = strInventory
        strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
        txtProcessor.Text = strInventory
        strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
        txtVideo.Text = strInventory
        strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
        txtForm.Text = strInventory
        strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
        txtRam.Text = strInventory
        strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
        txtVram.Text = strInventory
        strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
        txtHd.Text = strInventory
        strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
        chkWireless.CheckState = strInventory
    End If
End Sub
```

**But**...your whole approach is very limiting as you'll only be able to move FORWARD in your file; you can't go backwards.  Consider creating a CLASS to hold that information and storing instances of it in a List(Of SomeClass).  Another option might be to use a DataTable.

Comment: Yeah moving backwards was my next goal after I was able to atleast move forward. I'm required to store all of the values in a text file.

Comment: @Devin in that case I'd strongly consider using a standard serialisable text format such as XML or JSON...much easier to work with than creating your own arbitrary format. You'll just end up solving all the same problems again which these formats have already dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I have tested it and made some slight improvements. Also, you need to change the inventory.txt file to have a blank line at the beginning. I posted the revised file after the following code:

```
    'This should be public and set to 1 at initial startup or you can save the value
    '  in a separate file when you close the program and read it when you open it up.
    Dim _lngLineLocation As Long = 1

    Public Sub MoveForward()
        Dim lngCurLine As Long

        'The using statement helps to keep your memory free.
        Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader("inventory.txt")

            lngCurLine = 1
            Do Until (lngCurLine > _lngLineLocation) Or sr.EndOfStream
                sr.ReadLine()
                lngCurLine += 1
            Loop

            If Not sr.EndOfStream Then
                Dim strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
                txtManufacturer.Text = strInventory
                strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
                txtProcessor.Text = strInventory
                strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
                txtVideo.Text = strInventory
                strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
                txtForm.Text = strInventory
                strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
                txtRam.Text = strInventory
                strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
                txtVram.Text = strInventory
                strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
                txtHd.Text = strInventory
                strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
                chkWireless.CheckState = strInventory

                lngCurLine += 8
            End If

            sr.Close()
        End Using

        _lngLineLocation = lngCurLine

    End Sub

    Public Sub MoveBackward()
        Dim lngCurLine As Long

        'The using statement helps to keep your memory free.
        Using sr As New System.IO.StreamReader("inventory.txt")

            _lngLineLocation -= ((8 + 1) * 2)
            _lngLineLocation = Math.Max(_lngLineLocation, 1)
            lngCurLine = 1
            Do Until (lngCurLine > _lngLineLocation) Or sr.EndOfStream
                sr.ReadLine()
                lngCurLine += 1
            Loop


            Dim strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
            txtManufacturer.Text = strInventory
            strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
            txtProcessor.Text = strInventory
            strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
            txtVideo.Text = strInventory
            strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
            txtForm.Text = strInventory
            strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
            txtRam.Text = strInventory
            strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
            txtVram.Text = strInventory
            strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
            txtHd.Text = strInventory
            strInventory = sr.ReadLine()
            chkWireless.CheckState = strInventory

            lngCurLine += 8
            sr.Close()

        End Using

        _lngLineLocation = lngCurLine

    End Sub
```

And finally, here is the text file modification (notice the first blank line added)

```
Dell
i5
Nvidia
Desktop
8
2
600
1

TestComp
TestProc
TestGraph
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
0

Dell2
i52
Nvidia2
Desktop2
82
22
6002
12

TestComp2
TestProc2
TestGraph2
Test12
Test22
Test32
Test42
02
```